# Prove $f(x)=x^3$ is not uniformly continuous in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, uniform-continuity

I wanted to post here my solution and check if I'm right.
Also, I wanted to know how can you prove it with "Formal" way with Epsilon-Delta (I saw some posts but most people jump immediately to a solution).

My try :

I will take the sequences $x_n=n$ and $y_n=n+\frac {1}{n}$
$|x_n-y_n|=|n-n-\frac {1}{n}|=\frac {1}{n} \rightarrow 0$ (when $n \rightarrow \infty$)
but $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|=|n^3-(n+\frac{1}{n})^3|=\cdots=3n+\frac {3}{n} + \frac {1}{n^3} \rightarrow \infty$ (when $n\rightarrow \infty$).

which shows that the function is not uniformly continuous over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Looks good to me :)

Comment: Is there actually a way to calculate $\epsilon$ .$\delta$ or we just "predict" what it will be and then check it out?

Comment: The last paragraph here may be useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3930250/is-sinx2-uniformly-continuous-for-all-x-in-0-%e2%88%9e-where-is-my-error/3930265#3930265

Comment: In such cases I would pick $y=x+K\delta$. Where $K$ is a suitable constant.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's fine.

If you want's a $\varepsilon-\delta$ approach, it's almost the same thing. You want to prove that $f$ is not uniformly continuous, which means that$$(\exists\varepsilon>0)(\forall\delta>0)(\exists x,y\in\Bbb R):|x-y|<\delta\wedge\bigl|f(x)-f(y)\bigr|\geqslant1.$$Take $\varepsilon=1$. Now, if $\delta>0$, you take $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $\frac1n<\delta$. Now you take $x=n$ and $y=n+\frac1n$ and your computations show that, indeed,$$\bigl|f(x)-f(y)\bigr|\geqslant1.$$

Comment: Thank you ,I checked it , I get the same equation as previously and $3n + \frac {1}{n} + \frac {1}{n^3} \ge 3n \ge 3 > 1$

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.